# Printing contents from a TableLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, printing

I have a layout file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!-- 2 columns -->
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:text="Column 1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:text="Column 2" />
        </TableRow>

        <!-- edittext span 2 column -->
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:text="Column 1 &amp; 2" />
        </TableRow>

        <!-- just draw a red line -->
        <View
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#FF0000" />

        <!-- 3 columns -->
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:text="Column 1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:text="Column 2" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:text="Column 3" />
        </TableRow>

        <!-- display this button in 3rd column via layout_column(zero based) -->
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:text="Column 3" />
        </TableRow>

        <!-- display this button in 2nd column via layout_column(zero based) -->
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:text="Column 2" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:text="Column 2" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:text="Column 2" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button8"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:text="Column 2" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button9"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:text="Column 2" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button10"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:text="Column 2" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button11"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:text="Column 2" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I would now like to print this layout. The only printing documentation that I could find were [here](http://developer.android.com/training/printing/index.html), but none of these tell me how to print from a view. Is there any method or example out there which I can follow? Thanks

Comment: ' print this layout. ' ? What is printing a layout?

Comment: Basically the print option in an app... The layout decides what is displayed right? I basically want to print the content present within the app, when I click on the print option.. Basically normal printing..

Comment: And how should the output look like?

Comment: Just like a normal print preview, which can print to pdf or a network printer.. In this case, since the table is scrollable, it should ideally have the rows and columns that are displayed, and dynamically calculate the number of pages it will take to print the table...

Comment: So not only the content of the layout but the complete gui?

Comment: In this case, the content including the table rows and columns. Even the content that is not visible in the screen...

Comment: So what has this all to do with a table layout? Would there be any difference with other layouts?

Comment: No.. I just want to print the active area and the area not displayed on the screen as well

Comment: In this case,  I need the horizontal and vertical  lines separating the various cells to be displayed as well..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76777/discussion-between-maddy-and-greenapps).